# Writing a 2-D List to a File, Reading it out and Re-Using saved List

Tags: python, list, file, text

I would like to write a 2-D array to a Python 3  txt file.

e.g.

```
 My_list = ['Hello', 'World', 0], ['Pretty', 'World', 1], ['Tired', 'World', 2]]
```

going into my_text.txt.

I have tried loads of approaches none of which I can recommend as I get a variety of results including 1 element Lists:

```
["['Hello', 'World', 0], ['Pretty', 'World', 1], ['Tired', 'World', 2]"]
```

and lists of strings:

```
["[Hello', 'World', 0]", "['Pretty', 'World', 1]", "['Tired', 'World', 2]"]
```

along with other wonderful results.
Does anyone know some of some simple straightforward code for this or a tutorial?
Just doing this out of curiosity, tbh and am struggling badly.

I would like to be able to read my List out from the file again and use it fully as a List once again 
e.g, `print(my_list[0][0])` yields `'Hello'`

Comment: Can you post some of the code you tried? Then we can give you pointers on where you might have gone the wrong way...

Comment: @LoosaBway "I would like to be able to read my List out from the file again and use it fully as a List once again" the problem is you are simply writing the string representation of a list to a file, and calling that serialization. As other answers here suggest, you should simply use one of the built-in serialization formats, JSON, YAML, pickle (not mentioned yet). Otherwise, you have to parse the string representation yourself. The important point is that what you save in the file *isn't a list*

Answer (score 2):

`json` is good at serializing lists/dicts/numbers/strings:

```
import json 

My_list = [['Hello', 'World', 0], ['Pretty', 'World', 1], ['Tired', 'World', 2]]

#write to file
with open("data.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(My_list, file)

#read from file
with open("data.json") as file:
    new_list = json.load(file)

print(new_list)
```

Result:

```
[['Hello', 'World', 0], ['Pretty', 'World', 1], ['Tired', 'World', 2]]
```

Comment: But as I have spent a few hours on this exercise with, I think(?) the difficulty arising from the tendency of various python text file instructions to add speech marks to what is saved / retrieved, I would like to beat this problem, I guess, just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account also **yaml**. Requires to install **pyyaml** (`pip install pyyaml`).

```
import yaml
```

Save the list object to file:

```
my_list = [['Hello', 'World', 0], ['Pretty', 'World', 1], ['Tired', 'World', 2]]

with open('my_list.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(my_list, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

The output file looks like this:

```
- - Hello
  - World
  - 0
- - Pretty
  - World
  - 1
- - Tired
  - World
  - 2
```

To load back the list:

```
with open("my_list.yml", 'r') as inputfile:
    my_list_back = yaml.load(inputfile)
```

---

To handle directly string you could use the standard library [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), this is a simple example, you can customise further.

```
import ast

string_list = (str(my_list)) # convert tostring then save it to file
print(string_list.__class__) # it's a string
reconverted_list = ast.literal_eval(string_list) # convert back with ast
print(reconverted_list.__class__) # it's a list
```

Than a basic read/write could be:

```
with open('my_list.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(my_list))

with open('my_list.txt', 'r') as file:
    my_list_back = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
```

Comment: I would really like to beat the challenge of just using string and file reading methods - handling the various speech marks seems to be just such a difficult thing

Comment: I added an edit to my post, if I get what you mean. You need to interprete e string as a different object (list in this case), so, you could look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html.

Answer (score 0):

Hi anyone who is interested.

I wanted to save an array into a Python Text File and Retrieve it fully so that I could address all elements.

I persevered with my problem and solved it with what is very messy code, I'm sure.

The code below does what I wanted to do.

Pointless exercise but I just had to do it.

Thanks for your help and ideas.

```
my_list = []
my_list_669 = []

def create_list():
    #Creating the list

    for x in range(5):
        my_list.append(["Hello", "World", x])

    print("my_list = ", my_list)


def save_list_to_file():
    #creating the string

    string_1 = ""

    for item in my_list:
        string = item[0] + "," + item[1] + "," + str(item[2]) + "\n"
        string_1 += string
        #adds records to a string with a line return after each record

    with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(string_1)


def recover_list():

    with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
            tiing = f.read().splitlines()
            #splits lines at \n and inserts into array called 'tiing'
            #each item is equivalent to a record

    for items1 in tiing:
        my_list_69 = items1.split(",")
        #splits the array items in ting at "," mark
        #these are now in an array called 'my_list_69'
        #below I access all items from within the list
        #and append them to a temporary sub-list

        sub_list = []
        for items in my_list_69:
            sub_list.append(items)

        my_list_669.append(sub_list)  this reconstructs the list


create_list()
save_list_to_file()
recover_list()

Testing:
print(my_list_669)
print(my_list_669[0])
print(my_list_669[0][2])
for items in my_list_669:
    print(items)
```